# converting rgb image to cmyk using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have image that i want to convert from `rgb` to `cmyk` using color profile.

Here is the image that i am using[image]

And the peace of code that i am using to convert into cmyk.

```
$IMagick = new IMagick();
$IMagick->clear();
$IMagick->readImage($image);
$IMagick->transformImageColorspace(12);
$icc_cmyk = file_get_contents("USWebUncoated.icc");

$IMagick->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
$IMagick->writeImage ($image2);
```

And here is the output image that i got.
[image]

I then checked color space and yes it is cmyk, but you can mark that green color is change though. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It is known that converting RGB to CMYK can change colors. Also browsers hae challenges rendering CMYK images properly. There is nothing you are doing wrong.